# Evaluate a multiple sequence alignment

Tags: python, alignment

I am using python to doing multiple sequence alignment.for evaluate the alignment I use Weighted sum of pairs score (WSP) for three sequences seq1, seq2 and seq3, as we know the score is calculate as follows:
first calculate the score of (seq1,seq2), and score of(seq1,seq3) and score of (seq2,seq3)

```
WSP=score(seq1,seq2)+score(seq1,seq3)+score(seq2,seq3)
```

**python code:**

```
def wsp():
        w=1
        dis=sum_distance(seq1,seq2,seq3)
        wsp=w*dis
        return wsp
```

now, I want to use a fasta file which contains many sequences.how can I calculate the WSP score for all sequences in a fasta file.

where **sum_distance** is a function to calculate distances between sequences

Comment: What is the expected output? A 3d-matrix?

Comment: Do you want to get all possible triples of sequences, and compute the WSP of each triple?

Comment: Have you looked into using [Biopython](http://www.biopython.org)? I haven't checked if it includes WSP or sum of distances, but I wouldn't be surprised if it did. It includes all sorts of tools for working with and aligning sequences, and is **much** easier than coding everything yourself.

Comment: for example for the three sequences `seq1='AG-GT' seq2='AG-GT and seq3='ACT-T'` the WSP function for the three sequences  score gives **8**.

Comment: not for each triple but for all sequences in the file

Comment: Are you looking for how to "not specify" how many sequences get sent to the sum_distance function?  What do you mean "not for each triple but for all sequences"?

Comment: no, the same thing for sum_distance as WSP .I use three sequences as example.but now, if I have n sequences how can I aplly  the above function to n sequences?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to run sum_distance function over each pair of sequences in your file:

```
total_distance = 0  
with open('yourfile.fa', 'r') as sequences_list_1:
    for key_1, seq_1 in enumerate(sequences_list_1):
        with open('yourfile.fa', 'r') as sequences_list_2:
            for key_2, seq_2 in enumerate(sequences_list_2):
                if key_1 < key_2:
                    total_distance += sum_distance(seq_1, seq_2)
```

Comment: this code gives me a score great than the real score for example for I have three sequences the code must calculate sum_distance(seq1,seq2) than sum_distance(seq1,seq3) and sum_distance(seq2,seq3) , than , calcul the **total distance**sum_distance(seq2,seq3)+ sum_distance(seq1,seq3)+sum_distance(seq2,seq3). and how can I do that for a file contains n sequences?